# Alternatives to ViewData?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, view, controller, server-side, viewdata

I'm pretty new to MVC, ASP.net, and, well, server-side scripting in general.

I was watching a tutorial video at www.asp.net/mvc where the person was explaining a template. He explained that the controller using viewdata to send information to the view.

Correct me if I'm wrong, but I believe it was used like this:

CONTROLLER: `ViewData["PropertyName"] = value;`

VIEW: `<p><%= ViewData["PropertyName"] %></p>`

Is this correct use?

What would be a better way to do it, instead of using ViewData, and what's bad about it?

Comment: You should really stick to a single question per post. I would move the "How is Html.Encode() used" question to a separate question since it's unrelated to the original.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are very view situations that I would advocate the use of the ViewData collection for.

For the most part, I would use [Strongly Typed Views](http://www.howmvcworks.net/OnViews/BuildingAStronglyTypedView) with individual [View Models](http://geekswithblogs.net/michelotti/archive/2009/10/25/asp.net-mvc-view-model-patterns.aspx) for each View.

Answer (score 1):

Rather than using the ViewData a better approach would be to create a new Model object and pass that to the View which is strongly typed to the Model.

**Model** (Models/MyModels.cs)

```
public class MyModel
{
    public string PropertyName { get; set; }
}
```

**View** (View/My/Index.aspx)

```
<%@ Page Language="C#" Inherits="ViewPage<MyModel>" %>
<p><%=Model.PropertyName %></p>
```

**Controller** (Controllers/MyController.cs)

```
public class MyController : Controller
{
    public ActionResult Index()
    {
        MyModel model = new MyModel()
        {
            PropertyName = "My Property Name"
        };

        return View(model);
    }
}
```

---

Html.Encode can be used like this:

```
<%=Html.Encode(someObject) %>
```

or this if you're [using ASP.NET 4.0](http://weblogs.asp.net/scottgu/archive/2010/04/06/new-lt-gt-syntax-for-html-encoding-output-in-asp-net-4-and-asp-net-mvc-2.aspx)

```
<%: someObject %>
```

Comment: I assume that you meant `<%=model.PropertyName %>` instead of `<%=Model.PropertyName %>` ?

Answer (score 1):

Justin is correct regarding ViewData usage, as well as using View Models (This is definitely the solution that will probably most fit your needs).

The `Session` is another option, but it can tend to be a slippery slope, but you did ask for alternatives.

Answer (score 0):

ViewData is good for complete random data that you're not sure what you're going to need.

If you're constructing well-defined views you'll want to use Strongly Typed Views. These let your view inherit from a particular business object (or, more usefully, a ViewModel) to display the data. In this situation, instead of ViewData["SomeProperty"] you could have access to a strongly-typed Model member ie Model.SomeProperty.

Also, Html.Encode is meant to be put around data elements that repeat user-entered data. It is meant to prevent HTML injection.